# jQuery Multiselect length return default value when I use history.go(-1);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-select dropdown and external div that post the number of selections.  When I save the document as XML a window opens with an option to go back (I am using onclick="history.go(-1);").
Everything works except that the number of selection is = 0 even if the input has some elements selected.

Thanks.

**java script code**

```
$("#airlaine").change(function () {
    var count = $(".k-multiselect-wrap li").length;
    //console.log(count);
    $('#displaycount').text(count);
});
```

**html code**

```
<div class="col-md-4 block">
    <div class="iconqsai navy">
        <p class="icontitle">QSAI</p>
        <h4 id="displaycount" class="displaycount" name="aircount" value=""><?php if ($airlainecount != ""){echo $airlainecount;} else {echo "0";} ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="grayArea airline">
        <div class="PanelMultiSelect"></div>
        <select id="airlaine" name="airlines[]" multiple="multiple" class="numairline">
           <option value="AA" <?php if (in_array("AA", $airline)) {echo "selected";}?> >AC</option>
           <option value="AB" <?php if (in_array("AB", $airline)) {echo "selected";}?> >AF</option>
           <option value="AC" <?php if (in_array("AC", $airline)) {echo "selected";}?> >ANA</option>
           <option value="AD" <?php if (in_array("AD", $airline)) {echo "selected";}?> >EIL</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to count list of `.k-multiselect-wrap li` or `#airlaine` selection?

for `#airlaine` selection:

```
$("#airlaine").change(function () {
    var count = $("#airlaine option:selected").length;
    $('#displaycount').text(count);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point is when I save and get back the value of count doesn't appear in any case.